# How to color Telerik Kendo UI pie chart wedges?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using the Telerik Kendo Pie Chart and I want to be able to color the wedges.

The following is the mark up for my Kendo UI pie chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createChart() {
    jQuery("#chart").kendoChart({
        theme: jQuery(document).data("kendoSkin") || "Metro",
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%"
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: "pie",
            data: [{
                category: "Remaining Work",
                value: 75,
                explode: true
            }, {
                category: "CIOs",
                value: 2
            }, {
                category: "Other Executives",
                value: 10
            }, {
                category: "Directors and Physicians",
                value: 13
            }]
        }],
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}%"
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        createChart();

        // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
        // the initial animation is visible
    }, 400);

    jQuery(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", function (e) {
        createChart();
    });
});
 </script>
```

I'd like the remaining work to be light gray. How do I accomplish this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In [Kendo UI DataViz](http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx), all charts support overriding the theme colours via the [`seriesColors` option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-seriesColors). This property will take an array of hexadecimal colour strings. For example:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
   ...
   seriesColors: ["#7c7c7c", ... ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it is an implementation from server side would be very interesting on the concept of avoiding Similar shades..please look in to the below code which iam inserting to bind the pie chart with colors
 If Not radChart Is Nothing Then
                    radChart.PlotArea.EmptySeriesMessage.TextBlock.Text = strNoData
                    radChart.SkinsOverrideStyles = False
                    Dim seriesColors As Color() = {Color.Aqua, Color.Bisque, Color.Chartreuse, Color.Coral, Color.DarkCyan, Color.DarkKhaki, Color.DimGray, Color.Yellow, Color.LightGreen, Color.Magenta, Color.Orange, Color.Purple, Color.SaddleBrown, Color.Silver, Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.Violet, Color.RosyBrown, Color.Olive, Color.Navy, Color.IndianRed}
                    Dim seriesPalette As New Palette("seriesPalette", seriesColors, True)
                    radChart.CustomPalettes.Add(seriesPalette)
                    radChart.SeriesPalette = "seriesPalette"
                    radChart.DataBind()
                End If
```